# How to read binary files into a library

Tags: javascript, typescript, lib

I'm writting a lib in TypeScript and I need to include some assets. This library will generate a PDF and will concat a button at the end. The button is taken from other PDF file. I used axios to read the button PDF from an URL location but I need that the button PDF file is included between the lib files and is installed when the library is installed from NPM. Then I change the code to use 'file-loader' but it didn't work properly when publish. And I have read in an article that not is good idea to "require binaries". My last attemp was to use fs.readFile to read files but it didn't work. I have read is for backend but this library is for frontend. By reasons I can't share all the code but I share some details.

Structure of the project:

```json
dist
 |_index.d.ts
 |_index.js
assets
 |_button.pdf
lib
 |_index.ts
node_modules
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
package.json:
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "libraryName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist/*",
    "assets/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "buclefor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.32",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add how do you use the said code so others can try to resolve your solve your publish problems and ensure that your button is still working. Otherwise, they're ways to encode binaries into client script directly using 64-based encoding (embedded image for instance). You could store your pdf like that in a JS file.

Comment: @Walfrat finally I have used webkpack file-loader. I find it a bit uggly because it forces to use webpack configs. I would prefer to make it an install-and-use library but it works fine.